# Retrieve any one maximum value from column containing array separated by semicolon in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have columns like

```
periodbal                  balancetype
-------------              -------------
0;15;11;-13;-16;20           ABS
22;25;-78;0;1                ABS
67;89;-36;83;90;55           ABS
…                            ACS
…
```

I want to retrieve

```
periodbal                  balancetype
---------                  -------------
20                            ABS
25                            ABS
90                            ABS
```

Comment: you need to write stored procedure or function

Comment: Can't we write using select statement??

Comment: As per the Project Requirement we need to use unpivot.. But i'm not getting how to use.. I'm new to sql.. Kindly can any one help me???

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195280/connect-by-clause-in-regex-substr

Comment: MySQL does not have an unpivot function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here is:

for each value of balancetype, extract all the values from periodbal column, convert them in separate rows and then calculate maximum for each row's balancetype value.

i.e.

```
PERIODBAL   BALANCETYPE     ID
0           ABS             1
15          ABS             1
11          ABS             1
-13         ABS             1
-16         ABS             1
20          ABS             1
```

SPLIT FOR ROW#2

```
22        ABS          2
25        ABS          2
-78       ABS          2
0         ABS          2
1         ABS          2
......
```

FINALLY, FETCH MAX(PERIODBAL) and group the data by columns balancetype, ID

```
CREATE TABLE SYS.TEST
(
  PERIODBAL    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  BALANCETYPE  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('0;15;11;-13;-16;20', 'ABS');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('22;25;-78;0;1', 'ABS');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('67;89;-36;83;90;55 ', 'ABS');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('0;15;10;-13;-16;23', 'ACS');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('0;14;11;-13;-16;25', 'ACS');
```

solution:

```
SELECT BALANCETYPE,MAX(BAL) AS PERIODBAL
FROM
(
SELECT SUB1.*, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( PERIODBAL, '[^;]+', 1, LVL)) BAL
FROM             (SELECT TEST.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BALANCETYPE ) UNIQ_ID FROM TEST) SUB1 , 
                (SELECT LEVEL LVL FROM DUAL,(SELECT  MAX(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(PERIODBAL, '[^;]+')))+1 AS MAX_BAL FROM TEST)  TEMP
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL<= TEMP.MAX_BAL ) SUB2
WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(PERIODBAL, '[^;]+'))+1>= SUB2.LVL
) GROUP BY BALANCETYPE, UNIQ_ID
```

output:

```
BALANCETYPE PERIODBAL
ACS         23
ABS         20
ABS         25
ABS         90
ACS         25
```

Hope it helped, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL**, you could try along

```
SELECT balanceType, MAX(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.periodBal, ';', n.n), ';', -1), SIGNED INTEGER)) maxValue
FROM SomeData t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.periodBal) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.periodBal, ';', '')))
GROUP BY periodBal, balanceType
ORDER BY periodBal, maxValue;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ffe73/13/0) (with the data slightly adjusted in order to check some border cases).

This borrowed from [SQL split comma separated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row#answer-19073575)
But the oldest SO reference for this approach, I was able to find, is [Creating a MySQL SET's from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858822/creating-a-mysql-sets-from-a-string#answer-1964575)